# How could I pass Vue Component by click event in Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

I am stuck with a passing Vue Component.

When a click event in a Vue Component is called, I want to pass Vue Component to other. 
I tried 'this' but it returned null.

If somebody can help me.
Here is my Code. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
...

<button type="button" class="confirmBtn" @click="$util.routerReplace(this, '/')">
    <span>confirm</span>
</button>
...

</template>

util.js
function routerReplace (foo, path) {
    console.log(foo)        // Now return null => Vue Component
    console.log(path)       // path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that all identifiers in the event handlers specified directly in the template are evaluated with `this` as the context. Therefore, you are passing `this.this` to `routerReplace` which is undefined.

It works if you use a component method as the event handler instead:

```js
var Component = {
  template: '<button type="button" @click="onClick">Confirm</button>',
  methods: {
    onClick: function() {
      this.$util.routerReplace(this, '/')
    },
  },
}

Vue.prototype.$util = {};
Vue.prototype.$util.routerReplace = function(component, path) {
  console.log(component, path);
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyComponent: Component,
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component/>
</div>
```